# How to do models mapping?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have one `Photo Entity`, where I want to save all the photos. I have other entity say `User` and `Post`. Both can have multiple photos. It should be a `many to many` mapping? Am I doing right? I am doing it using symfony2 & doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the multiplicity you need, you must fill this kind of phrases:

One A has ? B(s)
One B has ? A(s)

Example:
One user has **many** posts
One post has **one** author (or user)

This relation is a many-to-one, bidirectional, the relation could be named "posts" (with an s) and the inverse relation could be named "author" (without s)

Do the same with your other entities (edit your question to show what you get).

Answer (score 0):

The **association-mapping types** are described here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

> Real many-to-many associations are less common

The logic of your application is up to you. From my point of view:

Post (one post may have multiple photos):

```
<one-to-many field="photos" target-entity="Photo" mapped-by="post" />
```

User (one user may have multiple photos):

```
<one-to-many field="photos" target-entity="Photo" mapped-by="user" />
```

Finally Photo:

```
<many-to-one field="post" target-entity="Post" />
<many-to-one field="user" target-entity="User" />
```